# set up an SSO with applications using differents protocols (some using saml, others CAS and others OpenIDconnect) with keycloak

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, openid-connect, saml-2.0

I am really new to keycloak and here I am not doing too much ....
I managed to set up the sso with rocketchat and nextcloud using openID connect. But here I have to do it this time with applications using diferent sso protocols (SAML, CAS, OpenID connect). Already, I would like to know if it is possible. And if so, how to do it.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a brief description, code, errors of your search/research efforts as is suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at Keycloak's features described in the [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#features).

In short yes you can do SSO between Oidc and SAML clients on the same realm. It does not support CAS by default, however you can use a [CAS extension](https://www.keycloak.org/extensions.html) to add that functionality.

https://github.com/Doccrazy/keycloak-protocol-cas